# Why transition when collapsing header with jQuery doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I wanted to make my header collapse when user scrolls down and reveal when they scroll up. So, I found this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariusc23/s6mLJ/31/) on the Internet and tried to add this functionality into my project.

Here's my markup:

```
  <header class="nav-down">
    <div class="header"><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/dog.png" class="logo"><span class="title">Dogs</span></a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/home.png" class="logo"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><img src="images/icons/search.png" class="logo"></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
```

There're way too much styles for all the elements inside the header, but here're the basic styles for the element `header` itself:

```
header
    transition all 0.2s ease-in-out
    z-index 999
    color #fff 
    background-color rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
    width 100%
    height 2.5em
    font-size 1.5em
    position fixed
    text-align left

.nav-up
    top -2.5em
```

The thing is that everything works fine, but there's no transition, i.e. the header appears and disappears as it should, but the transition is not performed.

Does anybody know what's going on here?

PS: I even tried doing `* { transition all .3s ease-in-out }`, but still no result.

Comment: Looks to be working just fine for me.  0.2s is very fast...

Comment: @smcka Well, I'm using stylus and it does vendor-prefixing for me. But I also tried to hardcode all the vendor prefixes and still no result

Comment: @JamesMontagne 0.2s is indeed quite fast, but it doesn't work even when I put 1s :)

Comment: Works fine for me in in your fiddle with the latest chrome.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Is it possible that some of my styles override that transition or make the header kinda `intransitionable`? although I also tried adding `!important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your stylus code to include a 'top' property:

```
header
    transition all 0.2s ease-in-out
    z-index 999
    color #fff 
    background-color rgba(0, 0, 0, .8)
    width 100%
    height 2.5em
    font-size 1.5em
    position fixed
    text-align left
    top 0

.nav-up
    top -2.5em
```